# javascript click web div

Tags: javascript, jquery

some need help with automatic clicking in javascript or jquery

I would like you to automatically click on

```
<button class="loginbutton">LOGUJ</button>
```

wait 5 seconds
then click

```
<input type="submit" value="LOGUJ" class="loginbutton" style="top: 5px;cursor:pointer">
```

wait 5 seconds
then click

```
<div class="closeCover new popup"></div>
```

wait 5 seconds
then click

```
<div class="element crimes active" id="tutorial_item_16">
        <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
```

wait 5 seconds
checked if everything is correct

```
<div class="value">79/79</div>
```

if so click

```
<div class="formSubmit doCrime myButton success" data-nerve="70" data-percent="95" data-need="70n">
                                <div class="in">$18 000</div>
                            </div>
```

then to wait 30 seconds and start all over again
my code

```
setTimeout(function() {
var xPathRes2 = document.evaluate ('//*[@id="welcome_container"]/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/button', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
xPathRes2.singleNodeValue.click();
    }, 3500);



setTimeout(function() {
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[value="LOGUJ"]');

inputElement.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // log "Hello" in the console when clicked
    console.log("hello");

})

// simulate a click on the input element with the click() method
inputElement.click();
    }, 5500);
setTimeout(function() {
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("closeCover new popup");
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) list[i].click();
    }, 6500);

setTimeout(function() {
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("wars");
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) list[i].click();
    }, 7500);

setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('tutorial_item_16').click();
    }, 9000);

setTimeout(function() {
var xPathRes2 = document.evaluate ('//*[@id="content_main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
xPathRes2.singleNodeValue.click();
    }, 11000);

setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('tutorial_item_14').click();
}, 12500);

setTimeout(function() {
var xPathRes1 = document.evaluate ('//*[@id="trainAll"]/div[2]/div/span', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
xPathRes1.singleNodeValue.click();
}, 13800);

setTimeout(function() {
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("myLink logout icon");
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) list[i].click();

    }, 15000);
```

Comment: I forgot to add the code I managed to do but it does not work; /

Comment: Add the code anyway because that's what you're asking us to debug. HTML/CSS/JS as a [mcve].

Comment: What is clicking on those elements meant to do, btw?

Comment: it is about logging into the game because I do not want to constantly relog my accounts to other ones and so that I would log in

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeOut` function like this.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('._my_save_button').trigger('click');
}, 3000);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm a novice can you show me all the clicks I asked to do in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you need the setInterval() function in javascript. i provide sample code for the use of this function.

**HTML**

```
<button id="mybtn" onclick="saySomething()">click me</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");


function saySomething(){
    alert("hello");
}

function clickFunc(){
    btn.click();
}

setInterval(clickFunc, 3000);
```

Comment: I don't have an id or onclick name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: someone will tell me